# Can we run opencv java on android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I done my task on java with opencv 2.4.9 now here I want to run this java API as it on android. Can I do this?

I have faced error at line System.loadLibrary("opencv_java249"); where I load native library of opencv 2.4.9.
All work is done in eclipse.

Comment: please have a look at the android chapters here:http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/df/d65/tutorial_table_of_content_introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate SDKs are available for Java and Android.

For installation and configuration of OpenCV sdk on android [click Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html).